# Git keeps recreating empty directory(?)

Tags: git

In my git repo, there is something with an icon of directory. I created it by mistake programatically as it was intented to be dir for test results with a date as name. However, I noticed a mistake in a script (it was adding a dot at the end) and `Ctrl+C` the process. Anyway, now I have a weird dir, its name is `2023-07-01T22_07_58.` and upon deleting it from Webstorm interface it is recreated immediately.

Deleting it from windows explorer is impossible, as it says it is no longer located there. I can't open it or add any files to it nor delete it using cmd nor powershell, nor remove it from git using `git rm`.

This is the result of `git clean -fd`

```
git clean -fd
warning: could not open directory '2023-07-01T22_07_58./': No such file or directory
warning: failed to remove 2023-07-01T22_07_58./: No such file or directory
```

Windows explorer, Webstorm shows dir name, but if I type `ls` in cmd it get's listed as a directory with empty name.

It's not uploadable to repo, but it is there and it hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
git rm -r --cached <directory_name>
then commit with -m
git push origin <branch_name>
```

Comment: fatal: pathspec '2023-07-01T22_07_58.' did not match any files

Comment: avoid using dot at the end

Comment: yeah, the dot was added by mistake in my script, but it managed to create a dir before I stopped ctrl+c it